# Taking a parser in argument and try to apply it zero or more times

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am currently writing a basic parser. A parser for type `a` takes a string in argument and returns either nothing, or an object of type `a` and the rest of the string.

Here is a simple type satisfying all these features:

```
type Parser a = String -> Maybe (a, String)
```

For example, I wrote a function that takes a `Char` as argument and returns a `Parser Char` :

```
parseChar :: Char -> Parser Char
parseChar _ [] = Nothing
parseChar c (x:xs)
    | c == x = Just (x, xs)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

I would like to write a function which takes a parser in argument and tries to apply it zero or more times, returning a list of the parsed elements :

```
parse :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
```

Usage example:

```
> parse (parseChar ' ') "    foobar"
Just ("    ", "foobar")
```

I tried to write a recursive function but I can't save the parsed elements in a list.

How can I apply the parsing several times and save the result in a list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to write a recursive function but I can't save the parsed elements in a list.

You don't need to "save" anything. You can use pattern matching. Here's a hint. Try to reason about what should happen in each case below. The middle case is a bit subtle, don't worry if you get that wrong at first. Note how `s` and `s'` are used below.

```
parse :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
parse p s = case p s of
   Nothing     -> ...    -- first p failed
   Just (x,s') -> case parse p s' of
      Nothing       -> ...   -- subtle case, might not be relevant after all
      Just (xs,s'') -> ...   -- merge the results
```

Another hint: note that according to your description `parse p` should never fail, since it can always return the empty list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I don't see how to merge in this case.

Comment: @ncas Since `x` is the result of the first parser, and `xs` is the list of the results of the next ones, we can write `x:xs` to merge them. We end up with `Just (x:xs, s'')` since `s''` is the rest of the string at the very end.